# Make a File/Folder Hidden on Windows with Java

Tags: java, file, directory, hidden

I need to make files and folders hidden on both Windows and Linux. I know that appending a '.' to the front of a file or folder will make it hidden on Linux.  How do I make a file or folder hidden on Windows?

Comment: `Files.setAttribute(path, "dos:hidden", true, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);`, via https://www.javacodeexamples.com/make-file-hidden-in-java-example/1065

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For Java 6 and below,

You will need to use a native call, here is one way for windows

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("attrib +H myHiddenFile.java");
```

You should learn a bit about win32-api or Java Native.

Comment: "native" means you're running platform specific code. `exec()` fires up a DOS/Windows shell to execute a DOS/Windows program.

Comment: what happens when this code is executed in Linux? Or how do I prevent it?

Answer (score 25):

The functionality that you desire is a feature of NIO.2 in the upcoming Java 7.

Here's an article describing how will it be used for what you need: [Managing Metadata (File and File Store Attributes)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html). There's an example with [DOS File Attributes](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html#dos):

```
Path file = ...;
try {
    DosFileAttributes attr = Attributes.readDosFileAttributes(file);
    System.out.println("isReadOnly is " + attr.isReadOnly());
    System.out.println("isHidden is " + attr.isHidden());
    System.out.println("isArchive is " + attr.isArchive());
    System.out.println("isSystem is " + attr.isSystem());
} catch (IOException x) {
    System.err.println("DOS file attributes not supported:" + x);
}
```

Setting attributes can be done using [DosFileAttributeView](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/javadoc/java/nio/file/attribute/DosFileAttributeView.html)

Considering these facts, I doubt that there's a standard and elegant way to accomplish that in Java 6 or Java 5.

Answer (score 19):

`Java 7` can hide a `DOS` file this way:

```
Path path = Paths.get("...");
Files.setAttribute(path, "dos:hidden", Boolean.TRUE, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
```

Earlier Java versions don't have an `API` for this.

The above code will not throw an exception on non-`DOS` file systems. If the name of the file starts with a period, then it will be a hidden on `UNIX` file systems.

Comment: The method getAttribute(String, LinkOption) is undefined for the type java.nio.file.Path (JDK 7u13)

Comment: Antonio, it must have been that way in the draft version of Java 7 that I used. I see that similar functionality is now in java.nio.file.Files.

Comment: You can use `Files.setAttribute` that will accept a `Path` to set the attribute on.

Answer (score 3):

this is what I use:

```
void hide(File src) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    // win32 command line variant
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("attrib +h " + src.getPath());
    p.waitFor(); // p.waitFor() important, so that the file really appears as hidden immediately after function exit.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

on windows, using java nio, Files

```
Path path = Paths.get(..); //< input target path
Files.write(path, data_byte, StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW); //< if file not exist, create 
Files.setAttribute(path, "dos:hidden", Boolean.TRUE, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS); //< set hidden attribute
```

Comment: Please add a description of how the code you posted addresses the user's question

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fully compilable Java 7 code sample which hides an arbitrary file on Windows.

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.attribute.DosFileAttributes;


class A { 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    { 
       //locate the full path to the file e.g. c:\a\b\Log.txt
       Path p = Paths.get("c:\\a\\b\\Log.txt");

       //link file to DosFileAttributes
       DosFileAttributes dos = Files.readAttributes(p, DosFileAttributes.class);

       //hide the Log file
       Files.setAttribute(p, "dos:hidden", true);

       System.out.println(dos.isHidden());

    }
 }
```

To check the file is hidden. Right-click on the file in question and you will see after the execution of the court that the file in question is truly hidden.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
String cmd1[] = {"attrib","+h",file/folder path};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd1);
```

Use this code it might solve you problem