# How to make a folder hidden using java

Tags: java, io

I want to create a hidden folder using java application. That program should work across platform. So How to write a program which can create hidden folder.

I have tried using

```
File newFile = new File("myfile");
newFile.mkdir();
```

It creates a directory which is not hidden.

Comment: May I ask why you need this? And do you know that hidden is a different concept in different operating systems?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294989/make-a-file-folder-hidden-on-windows-with-java

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The concept of hidden files/folders is very OS-specific and not accessible via the Java API.

In Linux, files and folders whose name begins with a dot are hidden per default in many programs - doing that is easy.

In Windows, "hidden" is a special flag stored in the file system. There is no Java API for changing it; you can use `Runtime.exec()` to run the [attrib](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/attrib.mspx) command.

Comment: While this works, I'd recommend you use Pal's Java 7 method mentioned below before resorting to the runtime hack (and check to make sure it's windows before doing the runtime hack)

Answer (score 30):

If you're using Java 7 you can use the new `java.nio.file.attribute` package like so:

```
Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("/j", "sa");
Files.setAttribute(path, "dos:hidden", true);
```

See more info at http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html

Or, if you're using an older version of Java and/or want to do it using `Runtime`, try this:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C attrib -s -h -r your_path");
```

See more info on [cmd](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cmd.mspx?mfr=true) and [attrib](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/attrib.mspx?mfr=true).

Answer (score 8):

under *nix you just rename the file so that

```
filename = ".".filename;
```

Answer (score 5):

To make a file or directory hidden under Unix, its name needs to start with a period (`.`).

To make a file hidden under Windows, you need to set the 'hidden' bit in its attributes. The Java standard library doesn't offer this capability (though there is a `file.isHidden()` method), and I don't offhand know any tool that does.

Answer (score 3):

You could use some form of a factory pattern for your crossplatforming needs.  But what everyone else said.  I'm afraid you can't quite make it plop out with one line of code, as I'm can just feel you want it to.  My condolences.

Answer (score 3):

that's OS job (and you are OS boss of course ). But you can execute attrib (Windows) command and tell OS(Windows) that you wanna make a folder "hidden".

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try
        {            
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            //put your directory path instead of your_directory_path
            Process proc = rt.exec("attrib -s -h -r your_directory_path"); 
            int exitVal = proc.exitValue();
        } catch (Throwable t)
          {
            t.printStackTrace();
          }

    }
}
```

Comment: It is necessary to wait for the process to exit before taking its exit code. `proc.waitFor()` should be used instead of `proc.exitValue()`, as the latter causes an `IllegalThreadStateException: process has not exited`

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps :

```
 1. make a folder with extension **.jad** and move your videos,photos, etc
    on that folder..
 2. now create same folder with extenson **.jar** (ex- if u create
    videos.jad then create videos.jar)
 3. finished .. Videos.jad will hide .. Delete the .jar  .jad will come
    again
```

Answer (score 0):

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "attrib": error=2, No such file or directory

In fact, the key to the question is what operating system you are using, MacOS and Windows have very different commands.

The commands provided online are all based on Windows, which is why your operation is invalid.

If you want to hide the folder on Windows, you can use the following code,

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("attrib +H " + dir.getAbsolutePath());
```

If you want to hide the folder on MacOS, you can use the following code,

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chflags hidden " + dir.getAbsolutePath());
```