# Hidding Folders using Java in Linux

Tags: java, ubuntu, hidden

I know there are already couple of questions asked but these are not solving my requirements. 
I need to hide a folder using java. up-till now everything is working fine as I am using Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mv Folder1 .Folder1"); in java but now I am unable to find the solution that how can I hide the folder which has spaces in name.

Note:

1. moving folders in linux is something different. e.g.

   mv My\ New\ Folder My\ Custom\ Folder
2. I am using ubuntu.

Comment: Go through this stackoverflow [link][1], it may prove a bit helpful.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999437/how-to-make-a-folder-hidden-using-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [File.renameTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File)).

e.g.

```
File f = new File("Path to your file");
f.renameTo(".Path to your file");
```

Comment: Well, I am really feeling stupid after seeing such a beautiful answer provided long ago by java community.

Comment: @IConfused: as a rule of thumb: don't use `System.exec()` for things that Java can do on its own. It has *lots* of pitfalls (and correct escaping/passing of arguments is but one of those).

Comment: @IConfused note the trap: `.renameTo()` does not throw an exception on failure, you have to check for its return value. If you use Java 7, you're better off using `Files.move()` (and ditch the `File` API)