# create hidden Folder in java code

Tags: java

i want to create **hidden folder** in java code.
i use this code:

```
   `

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    { 
        File f=new File(System.getProperty("user.home")+"Desktop/file");
        f.mkdir();
        String cmd="attrib +h "+f.getAbsolutePath(); 
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd); 
}
```

`

but the error is:

```
    `   Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "attrib": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1042)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:615)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:448)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:345)
    at filespermssion.testruntime.main(testruntime.java:22)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:135)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1023)
    ... 4 more
Java Result: 1`
```

can you help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999437/how-to-make-a-folder-hidden-using-java

Comment: Try `String cmd="attrib +h \""+f.getAbsolutePath();\"";`

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing `/` before `Desktop`, resulting in two directories that `mkdir` cannot do (`mkdirs` could have).

```
File f=new File(System.getProperty("user.home")+"/Desktop/file");
```

Comment: i add it but not work the problem is caused by : Cannot run program "attrib": error=2, No such file or directory