# How to hide a file at runtime in java

Tags: java, file

I have Java program where I create a file called `hd_details`, and store the hardware details of the machine that runs the program and install count. The install count is to restrict the exe to run 2 time only. I converted that program to an `exe` through Launch4j. When I run the exe, the file `hd_details` get extracted. I need to hide the file. Any suggestion?

Comment: Why don't you look for the exe with `tasklist` (win command) from within java (`Runtime.getRuntime().exec`) and just exit your program if it is already running?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make a File/Folder Hidden on Windows with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294989/make-a-file-folder-hidden-on-windows-with-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows you can try this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("attrib +H hd_details");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a file to both exist and "be hidden", you are wanting the *file-system* of the computer to do something. That puts you out of the domain of Java proper and into system dependent issues. You mentioned "an `exe`" so I guess you need this to work only on Windows? Or do you?

On POSIX systems a file can be anonymous (and therefore invisible) but existent by removing all hard links to it while holding it open. I do not beleive that truely invisible closed files are possible in POSIX. The `ls` command does not normally list files with names that begin with a dot (such as `.ssh`), which is used to hide configuration and state files from normal use, but seeing them is as simple as typing `ls -a`.