# How can modify/edit a file data which is inside a jar?

Tags: java, file, jar, persistence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can a Java program use files inside the .jar for read and write?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052311/how-can-a-java-program-use-files-inside-the-jar-for-read-and-write)

I am working on a Java project in which I want to write to a file which is inside a jar.
I know how to read it.

```
 URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("libs/page.properties");
 InputStream fin = url.openStream();
 if (fin != null)
 {
    ObjectInputStream objStream = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
    Object pageC = objStream.readObject();
    pageCount = Integer.parseInt(pageC.toString());
 }
```

Now how can I write a new value inside `page.properties` file?

Comment: You shouldn't be writing to a file inside a jar.

Comment: @BheshGurung But there is a requirement to do this.

Comment: *"But there is a requirement to do this."*  If I require pigs to fly, that will hardly make a difference to the fact they can't.

Comment: If you want to hide files from the user (e.g. game score, don't allow editing) just make the file hidden by calling `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("attrib +H score.dat");`. For more, see [Hidding Files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294989/make-a-file-folder-hidden-on-windows-with-java).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Sir i have tried many possible cases to do this. But i am not getting the successful case for it.This files is working as an counter for me, to avoid user-action to this file i have to put this file inside a jar.

Comment: @AndrewThompson unless, obviously, you're Pink Floyd [Pigs on the Wing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigs_on_the_Wing) :)

Comment: @Nishant Pink Floyd took a ***lot*** of psychoactive substances.  ;

Comment: *"to avoid user-action to this file i have to put this file inside a jar."*  It is easy for a user to access a file inside a Jar.  A Jar is a specialized Zip file.  But your code writes objects apparently.  They are much harder to edit.  If this game is giving prize money, the details should not be stored on the client side at all, but pushed to a server (with a whole lot more security problems).

Comment: You should really change the question to something like *"How to store game scores so user cannot easily hack them?"*  What you are doing will **not** lead to an answer to that question.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I an not working on a game project Sir.