# How to hide the files in the sd card which are created by my application?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make a File/Folder Hidden on Windows with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294989/make-a-file-folder-hidden-on-windows-with-java)

I want to insert the files into sd card and that files should not visible normally, It should be visible only through my application.

Comment: are you asking for possibility it work? are you asking for technical possibility? are you asking for other to code what you want? what actually have you tried?

Comment: If you place all your files in a subdirectory (that you create from your application), you could use the http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FilePermission.html API to remove "read" permission for anyone except the directory owner (i.e. your app). That should prevent other apps from listing the contents in that directory.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with hiding a file/folder on Windows.  This is an Android Development question and trying to hide a file on android is a valid and unrelated question.  The SD card can be browsed by the Android device itself, which last I checked, doesn't run Windows.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to hide files on your SD card from a file browser.. but if you have files that you don't want android to index and show in media players like avi or mp3 files, you just need to create a file called  `.nomedia` in the same directory as your media files.