# How to delete hidden files in windows 7

Tags: java, file, directory, hidden

I have created Hidden folder in windows from this [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294989/make-a-file-folder-hidden-on-windows-with-java).Now i have to delete one file in that hidden folder.

eg.**C:\program files\test\abc.xml**

I want to delete abc.xml and i have used following code for delete in java

```
String path="C:\program files\test\abc.xml"
 if(new File(path).exists()){
  new File(path).delete()
 }
```

The **attribute set as N** for this file instead of deleting. I do not know what happening?

**Note:** abc.xml file is encrypted file.

Can any one help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String path="C:\\program files\\test\\abc.xml"
```

Try escaping your backslashes and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks.but its not working.File is not deleted.i have edited the question.

Comment: I would suggest re-writing your delete code to test the delete function and report any exceptions it may encounter: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-delete-file-in-java/ if that doesn't work report back with more details like errors. Perhaps its a permissions problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
FileUtils.cleanDirectory(new File("C:\\\program files\\\test\\\"));
```

It will take care of everything in the directory.

Just need to add `Apache Commons IO` jar to your path.