# How to create a hidden file in any OS using Java

Tags: java, hidden-files

I have this code trying to create and write in my Json File, but how can I do it Hidden in any OS (Windows or Mac)

```
File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "Documents" + File.separator + "targetappConfig.json");

if (!(file.exists())) {

  org.json.simple.JSONArray userDetails = new org.json.simple.JSONArray();
  userDetails.add(userDetail);
  jsonObj.put("users", userDetails);
  FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
  fileWriter.write(jsonObj.toString());
  fileWriter.flush();
  fileWriter.close();
}
```

Comment: what's your definition for _hidden_?

Comment: You can't. (Because not all OS support hidden files. (Thanks God!))

Comment: You do this by creating an appropriate method for every OS family. There is no standard universal notion of "hidden" files. Also, a better way to do what you seem to be trying to do would be to keep your private files in a private folder intended for this sort of thing. (the appropriate `AppData` directory on Windows, `~/Library/Application Support/Your App Name/` on OS X, and `~/.config/yourappname/` on Linux.)

Comment: Is the goal just to store user preferences in a persistent place without the user wondering why a file suddenly appeared? Because then you could just use the [Preferences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) class to store the data in a place appropriate to the platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did was to creat a OSValidator and for each OS I encode my file and save it in a Application Dir (windows: appdata, mac: Application Suport). It seemed to be the easiest to do.

```
public class OSValidator {
    private static String OS = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();

    public static boolean isWindows(){
        return (OS.indexOf("win")>=0);
    }

    public static boolean isMac(){
        return (OS.indexOf("mac")>=0);
    }

    public static boolean isUnix() {
        return (OS.indexOf("nix") >=0 || OS.indexOf("nux") >=0 || OS.indexOf("aix") >= 0);
    }

    public static boolean isSolaris(){
        return (OS.indexOf("sunos") >=0);
    }
}



if (OSValidator.isWindows()) {
            System.out.println("This is Windows");
            file = new File(System.getenv("APPDATA") + File.separator + "TargetApp" + File.separator +"config.json");

            if (!file.exists()) {
                try {
                    FileUtils.forceMkdir(file.getParentFile());
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(LoginController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }

        } else if (OSValidator.isMac()) {
            System.out.println("This is Mac");

            file = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "Library" + File.separator + "Application Support"
                    + File.separator + "config.json");
        }
```

Comment: Why do you use `File.seperator`? As far as I know, java uses the right seperator on its own, when you use "/". Further, the Validator seems to be pretty equal to [this one](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-detect-os-in-java-systemgetpropertyosname/) ;)

Answer (score 1):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294989/make-a-file-folder-hidden-on-windows-with-java) for Windows and other operating systems that actually support the hidden file attribute. There are even multiple ways to do this.

For Unix/Linux, files and folders whose names start with dot are considered hidden (like `.ssh`, for instance). These are not visible by default. Surely the user can see them in one turns "show hidden files" on for explorer or uses `-a` for `ls`. Still, for the reasons like convenience reasons this should be sufficient.