# How to hide system protected file in you file manager

Tags: java, disk

I am using `File` and `FileSystemView` classes to extract diskinfo. The problem is when i get all the files in any directory there are also the files which are system protected files and i didn't want to show them. So is there is any way to check that this is a system protected file and then don't show it?

Comment: Your OS,Windows,Linux/Unix or Mac?

Comment: Currently on windows but it will also run on other OS too

Answer (score 3):

You can detect hidden files using `File.isHidden()` method. If you need to detect explicitly Windows system files, you can do it in Java 7 using its NIO.2 interface. See [Managing Metadata](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html) in The Java Tutorials, there is an example in Section *DOS File Attributes* how to check for the system flag.

See also [Make a File/Folder Hidden on Windows with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1294989/1333025)