# Hide subfolders inside a folder in java

Tags: java, io

I have a scenario where I need to hide my some folders which contain some files.
I search a lot over the internet but did not get any good solution.
I need to hide subfolders not the whole directory.
Here is the code which I am using

```
Process _p = null;
         try {
             _p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("attrib +H " + t.getPath());
              _p.waitFor();
         } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
             java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(newFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
```

where t = path tp that file
like `C:\parentFolder\subfolder1\subfolder2\book.xml`
I need to hide only `subfolder1\subfolder2\book.xml`

Please provide me some good solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "hide"? The OS feature?

Comment: yes I need to hide the subfolders.

Comment: So you want to toggle this OS feature through Java?

Comment: exactly this is what I am trying to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a File/Folder Hidden on Windows with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294989/make-a-file-folder-hidden-on-windows-with-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Java 7 solution

```
Path path = Paths.get("your/folder");
Files.setAttribute(path, "dos:hidden", true);
```

Or:

```
Path path = Paths.get("your/folder");
DosFileAttributeView attr = Files.getFileAttributeView(path, DosFileAttributeView.class);
attr.setHidden(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

use `DosFileAttributeView` , it has `setHidden()` method

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/DosFileAttributeView.html#setHidden(boolean)